# CodePage ID to CodePage name: GetEncoding equivalent in Delphi?

Tags: .net, delphi, encoding, winapi, codepages

I'm looking for a Win32 equivalent of the .Net Encoding.GetEncoding Method to be used in Delphi7.

What I would like to achieve is to convert a Codepage ID (ie.: 28592) to a Codepage name (iso-8859-2 in this case).

I've found a Win32 function called GetCPInfoEx, but that returns a long CodePage name, and I need the short one, like the ones listed on this page: (see Name column)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Thank you!

Comment: For people using the latest versions Delphi(XE), we have System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetEncoding(CodePageId).EncodingName

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my look-up table with code, feel free to use it.

```
type
  TCPData = record
    CPID: Integer;
    CPName: String;
  end;

const
  MaxEncodings = 140;

  Encodings: Array[0..MaxEncodings - 1] of TCPData =
  (
    (CPID: 37; CPName: 'IBM037'),
    (CPID: 437; CPName: 'IBM437'),
    (CPID: 500; CPName: 'IBM500'),
    (CPID: 708; CPName: 'ASMO-708'),
    (CPID: 720; CPName: 'DOS-720'),
    (CPID: 737; CPName: 'ibm737'),
    (CPID: 775; CPName: 'ibm775'),
    (CPID: 850; CPName: 'ibm850'),
    (CPID: 852; CPName: 'ibm852'),
    (CPID: 855; CPName: 'IBM855'),
    (CPID: 857; CPName: 'ibm857'),
    (CPID: 858; CPName: 'IBM00858'),
    (CPID: 860; CPName: 'IBM860'),
    (CPID: 861; CPName: 'ibm861'),
    (CPID: 862; CPName: 'DOS-862'),
    (CPID: 863; CPName: 'IBM863'),
    (CPID: 864; CPName: 'IBM864'),
    (CPID: 865; CPName: 'IBM865'),
    (CPID: 866; CPName: 'cp866'),
    (CPID: 869; CPName: 'ibm869'),
    (CPID: 870; CPName: 'IBM870'),
    (CPID: 874; CPName: 'windows-874'),
    (CPID: 875; CPName: 'cp875'),
    (CPID: 932; CPName: 'shift_jis'),
    (CPID: 936; CPName: 'gb2312'),
    (CPID: 949; CPName: 'ks_c_5601-1987'),
    (CPID: 950; CPName: 'big5'),
    (CPID: 1026; CPName: 'IBM1026'),
    (CPID: 1047; CPName: 'IBM01047'),
    (CPID: 1140; CPName: 'IBM01140'),
    (CPID: 1141; CPName: 'IBM01141'),
    (CPID: 1142; CPName: 'IBM01142'),
    (CPID: 1143; CPName: 'IBM01143'),
    (CPID: 1144; CPName: 'IBM01144'),
    (CPID: 1145; CPName: 'IBM01145'),
    (CPID: 1146; CPName: 'IBM01146'),
    (CPID: 1147; CPName: 'IBM01147'),
    (CPID: 1148; CPName: 'IBM01148'),
    (CPID: 1149; CPName: 'IBM01149'),
    (CPID: 1200; CPName: 'utf-16'),
    (CPID: 1201; CPName: 'unicodeFFFE'),
    (CPID: 1250; CPName: 'windows-1250'),
    (CPID: 1251; CPName: 'windows-1251'),
    (CPID: 1252; CPName: 'Windows-1252'),
    (CPID: 1253; CPName: 'windows-1253'),
    (CPID: 1254; CPName: 'windows-1254'),
    (CPID: 1255; CPName: 'windows-1255'),
    (CPID: 1256; CPName: 'windows-1256'),
    (CPID: 1257; CPName: 'windows-1257'),
    (CPID: 1258; CPName: 'windows-1258'),
    (CPID: 1361; CPName: 'Johab'),
    (CPID: 10000; CPName: 'macintosh'),
    (CPID: 10001; CPName: 'x-mac-japanese'),
    (CPID: 10002; CPName: 'x-mac-chinesetrad'),
    (CPID: 10003; CPName: 'x-mac-korean'),
    (CPID: 10004; CPName: 'x-mac-arabic'),
    (CPID: 10005; CPName: 'x-mac-hebrew'),
    (CPID: 10006; CPName: 'x-mac-greek'),
    (CPID: 10007; CPName: 'x-mac-cyrillic'),
    (CPID: 10008; CPName: 'x-mac-chinesesimp'),
    (CPID: 10010; CPName: 'x-mac-romanian'),
    (CPID: 10017; CPName: 'x-mac-ukrainian'),
    (CPID: 10021; CPName: 'x-mac-thai'),
    (CPID: 10029; CPName: 'x-mac-ce'),
    (CPID: 10079; CPName: 'x-mac-icelandic'),
    (CPID: 10081; CPName: 'x-mac-turkish'),
    (CPID: 10082; CPName: 'x-mac-croatian'),
    (CPID: 12000; CPName: 'utf-32'),
    (CPID: 12001; CPName: 'utf-32BE'),
    (CPID: 20000; CPName: 'x-Chinese-CNS'),
    (CPID: 20001; CPName: 'x-cp20001'),
    (CPID: 20002; CPName: 'x-Chinese-Eten'),
    (CPID: 20003; CPName: 'x-cp20003'),
    (CPID: 20004; CPName: 'x-cp20004'),
    (CPID: 20005; CPName: 'x-cp20005'),
    (CPID: 20105; CPName: 'x-IA5'),
    (CPID: 20106; CPName: 'x-IA5-German'),
    (CPID: 20107; CPName: 'x-IA5-Swedish'),
    (CPID: 20108; CPName: 'x-IA5-Norwegian'),
    (CPID: 20127; CPName: 'us-ascii'),
    (CPID: 20261; CPName: 'x-cp20261'),
    (CPID: 20269; CPName: 'x-cp20269'),
    (CPID: 20273; CPName: 'IBM273'),
    (CPID: 20277; CPName: 'IBM277'),
    (CPID: 20278; CPName: 'IBM278'),
    (CPID: 20280; CPName: 'IBM280'),
    (CPID: 20284; CPName: 'IBM284'),
    (CPID: 20285; CPName: 'IBM285'),
    (CPID: 20290; CPName: 'IBM290'),
    (CPID: 20297; CPName: 'IBM297'),
    (CPID: 20420; CPName: 'IBM420'),
    (CPID: 20423; CPName: 'IBM423'),
    (CPID: 20424; CPName: 'IBM424'),
    (CPID: 20833; CPName: 'x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended'),
    (CPID: 20838; CPName: 'IBM-Thai'),
    (CPID: 20866; CPName: 'koi8-r'),
    (CPID: 20871; CPName: 'IBM871'),
    (CPID: 20880; CPName: 'IBM880'),
    (CPID: 20905; CPName: 'IBM905'),
    (CPID: 20924; CPName: 'IBM00924'),
    (CPID: 20932; CPName: 'EUC-JP'),
    (CPID: 20936; CPName: 'x-cp20936'),
    (CPID: 20949; CPName: 'x-cp20949'),
    (CPID: 21025; CPName: 'cp1025'),
    (CPID: 21866; CPName: 'koi8-u'),
    (CPID: 28591; CPName: 'iso-8859-1'),
    (CPID: 28592; CPName: 'iso-8859-2'),
    (CPID: 28593; CPName: 'iso-8859-3'),
    (CPID: 28594; CPName: 'iso-8859-4'),
    (CPID: 28595; CPName: 'iso-8859-5'),
    (CPID: 28596; CPName: 'iso-8859-6'),
    (CPID: 28597; CPName: 'iso-8859-7'),
    (CPID: 28598; CPName: 'iso-8859-8'),
    (CPID: 28599; CPName: 'iso-8859-9'),
    (CPID: 28603; CPName: 'iso-8859-13'),
    (CPID: 28605; CPName: 'iso-8859-15'),
    (CPID: 29001; CPName: 'x-Europa'),
    (CPID: 38598; CPName: 'iso-8859-8-i'),
    (CPID: 50220; CPName: 'iso-2022-jp'),
    (CPID: 50221; CPName: 'csISO2022JP'),
    (CPID: 50222; CPName: 'iso-2022-jp'),
    (CPID: 50225; CPName: 'iso-2022-kr'),
    (CPID: 50227; CPName: 'x-cp50227'),
    (CPID: 51932; CPName: 'euc-jp'),
    (CPID: 51936; CPName: 'EUC-CN'),
    (CPID: 51949; CPName: 'euc-kr'),
    (CPID: 52936; CPName: 'hz-gb-2312'),
    (CPID: 54936; CPName: 'GB18030'),
    (CPID: 57002; CPName: 'x-iscii-de'),
    (CPID: 57003; CPName: 'x-iscii-be'),
    (CPID: 57004; CPName: 'x-iscii-ta'),
    (CPID: 57005; CPName: 'x-iscii-te'),
    (CPID: 57006; CPName: 'x-iscii-as'),
    (CPID: 57007; CPName: 'x-iscii-or'),
    (CPID: 57008; CPName: 'x-iscii-ka'),
    (CPID: 57009; CPName: 'x-iscii-ma'),
    (CPID: 57010; CPName: 'x-iscii-gu'),
    (CPID: 57011; CPName: 'x-iscii-pa'),
    (CPID: 65000; CPName: 'utf-7'),
    (CPID: 65001; CPName: 'utf-8')
  );

implementation

function GetEncoding(CPID: Integer): String;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 'iso-8859-2'; //put the default encoding here

  for I := 0 to MaxEncodings - 1 do
    if Encodings[I].CPID = CPID then
    begin
      Result := Encodings[I].CPName;
      break;
    end;
end;
```

Thanks to everyone for the answers, but this proved to be the only usable solution in this case...

Comment: In Indy 10 (http://www.indyproject.org), have a look at the lookup tables in its IdCharsets.pas unit.

Comment: If performance matters, using THashedStringList instead of a record set might improve lookup speed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [the IANA official names](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets)?  Since you want them correlated to Windows CP identifiers, I don't think you can do better than [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: So basically, I'll have to make my own lookup table?

Comment: @Ben - there are many codepages/names in use in the wild that do not appear in MS's list.  @Steve - Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [IMultiLanguage::GetCodePageInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741016%28VS.85%29.aspx), exported as part of MLang.dll.  It's included with IE4 and above.  You can create the import library yourself using Delphi's **Import Component...** command, or grab **MultiLanguage_TLB.pas** from Colin Wilson's [low-level utilities](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d9lowlevel.htm) package.

```
function CodePageToCharSet(ACodePage: Cardinal): string;
var
  MimeCPInfo: TMimeCPInfo;
  MultiLanguage: IMultiLanguage;
begin
  if Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_CMultiLanguage, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
     IID_IMultiLanguage, MultiLanguage)) and
     Succeeded(MultiLanguage.GetCodePageInfo(ACodePage, MimeCPInfo)) then
    Result := string(MimeCPInfo.wszWebCharset)
  else
    Result := 'US-ASCII';
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, it compiled but in practice it didn't work in some cases (for example it didn't recognize 28591 - iso-8859-1 which is a no-go).

Please see my "re-usable" answer below :-)

Comment: @Steve: Can verify. However, if you like, try the "IMultiLanguage2" interface. It seems to return the correct strings.

Comment: @Sertac et all - because WebCharset only is set when needing override over "family" BodyCharset - just print the registry and contemplate a bit. Developers should be curious, really :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the [LCIDToLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318698(v=VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: I believe locale ids are different from Codepage IDs. Locale IDs contain locale information, while Codepage IDs are just a unique ID, one per each codepage, iso-8859-2.

Answer (score 1):

Use search, Luke. Just old good text search. In RegEdit. For any cp short name you'd need :-)  *and remember, those IDs are really Internet MIME ids*

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\DataBase

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx this page hints that probably - just probably - that key exists since MSIE4 - in other words since Windows 98*

```
uses
{$IfDef MSWINDOWS}Registry, Windows, {$EndIf}
AnsiStrings;

/// todo - add implementation for non-Windows platforms
/// if anyone would need it :-)
/// probably via http://sourceforge.net/projects/natspec/
function CharSetByCodePage(const cp:Word): AnsiString;
{$IfDef MSWINDOWS }
var reg: TRegistry;
begin
// HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\DataBase\Codepage
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    if reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('MIME\DataBase\Codepage\' + IntToStr(cp)) then begin
       Result := Trim(AnsiString(reg.ReadString('WebCharset'))); // This key prevails, see #1251 for example
       if Result = '' then
          Result := Trim(AnsiString(reg.ReadString('BodyCharset')));
       if Result > '' then exit;
    end;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
  Raise EZXSaveException.Create('No charset (MIME id) found for codepage '+IntToStr(cp));
end;
{$Else}
begin
  Raise EZXSaveException.Create('Cannot get charset by numeric codepage on this platform.');
  //not implemented, perhaps http://sourceforge.net/projects/natspec/ ?
end;
{$EndIf}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TCPInfoEx = record
    MaxCharSize: UINT;
    DefaultChar: array[0..MAX_DEFAULTCHAR - 1] of Byte;
    LeadByte: array[0..MAX_LEADBYTES - 1] of Byte;
    UnicodeDefaultChar: WideChar;
    CodePage: UINT;
    CodePageName: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of Char;
  end;

function GetCPInfoEx(CodePage: UINT; Flags: DWORD; var lpCPInfoEx: TCPInfoEx): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll' name 'GetCPInfoExA';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CPInfoEx: TCPInfoEx;
begin
  if GetCPInfoEx(28592, 0, CPInfoEx) then
    ShowMessage(CPInfoEx.CodePageName);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks but did you test this code? It's the same code I was originally using and for me it doesn't only give back the 'iso-8859-2' string but some other gibberish information as well - I'm unable to consistently extract the actual codepage name from that...

Comment: Steve, I tested for CPs supported in my system and 'CodePageName' consists of the CP identifier and an informative text in paranthesis. For ex. for 28592 it returns "28592 (ISO 8859-2 Central Europe)". If parsing the text in the paranthesis does not suit you, I guess, you'd have to construct a lookup table yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, parsing the text wasn't possible, as there is no way to generate 'iso-8859-2' from '28592 (ISO 8859-2 Central Europe)'; Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Steve - sure, there is.  Drop everything outside and including the parenthesis, lowercase the ISO, replace the following space with a hyphen, and drop the rest of the text.