# How do I get a HTTP charset name from current Windows locale?

Tags: delphi, winapi, http, character-encoding

For HTTP upload of text files which have been created with the current OS locale, I would like to generate a header like

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-2
```

to allow the server proper processing of the text. Is there a Windows API function which returns the charset string for a given locale id?

Comment: @TLama: this returns "Locale Name for 0x10407 is de-DE_phoneb", but I need the charset, not the locale name in the HTTP header

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574289/codepage-id-to-codepage-name-getencoding-equivalent-in-delphi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the charset info.

Comment: I wonder how this answer was helpful when he already used it and didn't get the needed result.

Comment: See my edit - it was helpful, I use GetLocaleInfo and a map to find the corresponding charset name

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which uses the [`IMultiLanguage2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. I don't know if the [`GetCodePageInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa740992%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) covers all the code pages (I'm afraid because of the comments at [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574289/codepage-id-to-codepage-name-getencoding-equivalent-in-delphi/2576672#2576672) answer), but I don't know how to verify it.

```
const
  IID_IMultiLanguage2: TGUID = '{DCCFC164-2B38-11D2-B7EC-00C04F8F5D9A}';
  CLSID_CMultiLanguage: TGUID = '{275C23E2-3747-11D0-9FEA-00AA003F8646}';

type
  tagMIMECPINFO = packed record
    dwFlags: LongWord;
    uiCodePage: SYSUINT;
    uiFamilyCodePage: SYSUINT;
    wszDescription: array[0..63] of WideChar;
    wszWebCharset: array[0..49] of WideChar;
    wszHeaderCharset: array[0..49] of WideChar;
    wszBodyCharset: array[0..49] of WideChar;
    wszFixedWidthFont: array[0..31] of WideChar;
    wszProportionalFont: array[0..31] of WideChar;
    bGDICharset: Byte;
    padding : array [0..2] of Byte;
  end;

  tagMIMECSETINFO = packed record
    uiCodePage: SYSUINT;
    uiInternetEncoding: SYSUINT;
    wszCharset: array[0..49] of WideChar;
  end;

  tagRFC1766INFO = packed record
    lcid: LongWord;
    wszRfc1766: array[0..5] of WideChar;
    wszLocaleName: array[0..31] of WideChar;
  end;

  tagDetectEncodingInfo = packed record
    nLangID: SYSUINT;
    nCodePage: SYSUINT;
    nDocPercent: SYSINT;
    nConfidence: SYSINT;
  end;

  __MIDL_IWinTypes_0009 = record
    case Integer of
      0: (hInproc: Integer);
      1: (hRemote: Integer);
  end;

  _RemotableHandle = packed record
    fContext: Integer;
    u: __MIDL_IWinTypes_0009;
  end;

  tagSCRIPTINFO = packed record
    ScriptId: Byte;
    uiCodePage: SYSUINT;
    wszDescription: array[0..47] of WideChar;
    wszFixedWidthFont: array[0..31] of WideChar;
    wszProportionalFont: array[0..31] of WideChar;
  end;

type
  tagMIMECONTF = (
    MIMECONTF_MAILNEWS = $00000001,
    MIMECONTF_BROWSER = $00000002,
    MIMECONTF_MINIMAL = $00000004,
    MIMECONTF_IMPORT = $00000008,
    MIMECONTF_SAVABLE_MAILNEWS = $00000100,
    MIMECONTF_SAVABLE_BROWSER = $00000200,
    MIMECONTF_EXPORT = $00000400,
    MIMECONTF_PRIVCONVERTER = $00010000,
    MIMECONTF_VALID = $00020000,
    MIMECONTF_VALID_NLS = $00040000,
    MIMECONTF_MIME_IE4 = $10000000,
    MIMECONTF_MIME_LATEST = $20000000,
    MIMECONTF_MIME_REGISTRY = $40000000
  );

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IEnumCodePage
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {275C23E3-3747-11D0-9FEA-00AA003F8646}
// *********************************************************************//
  IEnumCodePage = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{275C23E3-3747-11D0-9FEA-00AA003F8646}']
    function Clone(out ppEnum: IEnumCodePage): HResult; stdcall;
    function Next(celt: LongWord; out rgelt: tagMIMECPINFO; out pceltFetched: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IEnumRfc1766
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {3DC39D1D-C030-11D0-B81B-00C04FC9B31F}
// *********************************************************************//
  IEnumRfc1766 = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{3DC39D1D-C030-11D0-B81B-00C04FC9B31F}']
    function Clone(out ppEnum: IEnumRfc1766): HResult; stdcall;
    function Next(celt: LongWord; out rgelt: tagRFC1766INFO; out pceltFetched: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IMLangConvertCharset
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {D66D6F98-CDAA-11D0-B822-00C04FC9B31F}
// *********************************************************************//
  IMLangConvertCharset = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{D66D6F98-CDAA-11D0-B822-00C04FC9B31F}']
    function Initialize(uiSrcCodePage: SYSUINT; uiDstCodePage: SYSUINT; dwProperty: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetSourceCodePage(out puiSrcCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetDestinationCodePage(out puiDstCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetProperty(out pdwProperty: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function DoConversion(var pSrcStr: Byte; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Byte;
      var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function DoConversionToUnicode(var pSrcStr: Shortint; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Smallint;
      var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function DoConversionFromUnicode(var pSrcStr: Smallint; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Shortint;
      var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IEnumScript
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {AE5F1430-388B-11D2-8380-00C04F8F5DA1}
// *********************************************************************//
  IEnumScript = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{AE5F1430-388B-11D2-8380-00C04F8F5DA1}']
    function Clone(out ppEnum: IEnumScript): HResult; stdcall;
    function Next(celt: LongWord; out rgelt: tagSCRIPTINFO; out pceltFetched: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IMultiLanguage2
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {DCCFC164-2B38-11D2-B7EC-00C04F8F5D9A}
// *********************************************************************//
  IMultiLanguage2 = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{DCCFC164-2B38-11D2-B7EC-00C04F8F5D9A}']
    function GetNumberOfCodePageInfo(out pcCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCodePageInfo(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; LangId: Word; out pCodePageInfo: tagMIMECPINFO): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetFamilyCodePage(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; out puiFamilyCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function EnumCodePages(grfFlags: LongWord; LangId: Word; out ppEnumCodePage: IEnumCodePage): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCharsetInfo(const Charset: WideString; out pCharsetInfo: tagMIMECSETINFO): HResult; stdcall;
    function IsConvertible(dwSrcEncoding: LongWord; dwDstEncoding: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertString(var pdwMode: LongWord; dwSrcEncoding: LongWord; dwDstEncoding: LongWord;
      var pSrcStr: Byte; var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Byte; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringToUnicode(var pdwMode: LongWord; dwEncoding: LongWord; var pSrcStr: Shortint;
      var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Smallint; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringFromUnicode(var pdwMode: LongWord; dwEncoding: LongWord; var pSrcStr: Smallint;
      var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Shortint; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringReset: HResult; stdcall;
    function GetRfc1766FromLcid(locale: LongWord; out pbstrRfc1766: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetLcidFromRfc1766(out plocale: LongWord; const bstrRfc1766: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
    function EnumRfc1766(LangId: Word; out ppEnumRfc1766: IEnumRfc1766): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetRfc1766Info(locale: LongWord; LangId: Word; out pRfc1766Info: tagRFC1766INFO): HResult; stdcall;
    function CreateConvertCharset(uiSrcCodePage: SYSUINT; uiDstCodePage: SYSUINT; dwProperty: LongWord;
      out ppMLangConvertCharset: IMLangConvertCharset): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringInIStream(var pdwMode: LongWord; dwFlag: LongWord; var lpFallBack: Smallint;
      dwSrcEncoding: LongWord; dwDstEncoding: LongWord; const pstmIn: IStream; const pstmOut: IStream): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringToUnicodeEx(var pdwMode: LongWord; dwEncoding: LongWord; var pSrcStr: Shortint;
      var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Smallint; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT; dwFlag: LongWord;
      var lpFallBack: Smallint): HResult; stdcall;
    function ConvertStringFromUnicodeEx(var pdwMode: LongWord; dwEncoding: LongWord; var pSrcStr: Smallint;
      var pcSrcSize: SYSUINT; var pDstStr: Shortint; var pcDstSize: SYSUINT; dwFlag: LongWord;
      var lpFallBack: Smallint): HResult; stdcall;
    function DetectCodepageInIStream(dwFlag: LongWord; dwPrefWinCodePage: LongWord; const pstmIn: IStream;
      var lpEncoding: tagDetectEncodingInfo; var pnScores: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function DetectInputCodepage(dwFlag: LongWord; dwPrefWinCodePage: LongWord; var pSrcStr: Shortint;
      var pcSrcSize: SYSINT; var lpEncoding: tagDetectEncodingInfo; var pnScores: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function ValidateCodePage(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; var hwnd: _RemotableHandle): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetCodePageDescription(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; lcid: LongWord; lpWideCharStr: PWideChar;
      cchWideChar: SYSINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function IsCodePageInstallable(uiCodePage: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetMimeDBSource(dwSource: tagMIMECONTF): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetNumberOfScripts(out pnScripts: SYSUINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function EnumScripts(dwFlags: LongWord; LangId: Word; out ppEnumScript: IEnumScript): HResult; stdcall;
    function ValidateCodePageEx(uiCodePage: SYSUINT; var hwnd: _RemotableHandle; dwfIODControl: LongWord): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

function GetSystemDefaultUILanguage: LANGID; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetSystemDefaultUILanguage';

implementation

function CodePageToCharSet(const ACodePage: Cardinal; const ALangID: LANGID): string;
var
  CodePageInfo: tagMIMECPINFO;
  MultiLanguage: IMultiLanguage2;
begin
  Result := '';

  if CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMultiLanguage, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMultiLanguage2, MultiLanguage) = S_OK then
    if MultiLanguage.GetCodePageInfo(ACodePage, ALangID, CodePageInfo) = S_OK then
      Result := CodePageInfo.wszWebCharset;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(LowerCase(CodePageToCharSet(GetACP, GetSystemDefaultUILanguage)));
end;
```

Comment: You can check [here](http://uploading.com/files/4985a665/Code%2BPage%2BIdentifiers.pdf/) the comparison table of the .NET aliases you've mentioned and the results from the `tagMIMECPINFO.wszWebCharset` by calling [GetCodePageInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa740992%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stefans link, I was able to solve the problem partially: this code displays **1252**, which according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) has the '.NET Name' **windows-1252**.

**Update**: the mapping from Charsets to Code Page Identifiers can be done with **Protocols\IdCharsets** which is included in Internet Direct (Indy).

```
program Project22;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows, Dialogs;

const  
    ID = LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE;
var
   BufSize: Integer;
   Result: string;
begin
   BufSize := GetLocaleInfo(GetUserDefaultLCID, ID, nil, 0);
   SetLength(Result, BufSize);
   GetLocaleinfo(GetUserDefaultLCID, ID, PChar(Result), BufSize);
   SetLength(Result, BufSize - 1);
   ShowMessage(Result);
end.
```